# Parentheses around string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was reading [Marionette's source code](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/helpers.js#L135) and I came across something like:

```
if (_.isObject(message)) {
    message = (
      message.prev + ' is going to be removed in the future. ' +
      'Please use ' + message.next + ' instead.' +
      (message.url ? ' See: ' + message.url : '')
    );
}
```

Why exactly is `message` wrapped in parentheses? What does that do?

Comment: I don't think the outer-most does anything. Probably the author used it for readability reasons. The inner is needed for the conditional (?) operator.

Comment: You can put any expression in parentheses, it is optional, but is often used to define presendence as operator precedence can be overridden by wrapping in parentheses, or make code more readable. In this case the outer parentheses aren't really needed

Comment: have you tried to remove the parenthesis if it has the same result?

Comment: Actually the ternary wrap does not even seem to be necessary - at least not in Chrome. It USED to be necessary

Comment: @mplungjan The way I understand it, they are required.  [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/qxrqk4xt/1/)

Comment: @mplungjan For `"a"+"b"?"yes":"no"`, do you get `yes` or `ayes`? If you get `ayes`, you should file a bug in Chromium for whatever version you're using.

Comment: That is not a valid ternary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific example, the outer parentheses do not serve any function, other than (arguably) improving readability.

This code is functionally identical:

```
if (_.isObject(message)) {
    message = 
        message.prev + ' is going to be removed in the future. ' +
        'Please use ' + message.next + ' instead.' +
        (message.url ? ' See: ' + message.url : '');
}
```

The parentheses around the ternary operator are added so the ternary operator doesn't evaluate everything before the `message.url`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the outer-most does anything. Probably the author used it for readability reasons. The inner is needed for the conditional (?) operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly for readability.
With or without, the functionality  does not change.